# This command is not available when running the Angular CLI inside a workspace

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I know that usally this error is triggered when you try to serve the angular application inside of a wrong directory, but in my case it is triggered when I try to create an Angular application, with the command ng new myapp.
I used latest cli version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sure you have angular.json in that folder

Comment: You are right, I don't know how it is possible :(, it is a folder where there are all my projects folder, I don't Know how can be happened. You save my day